# Random string rules

Tags: php

I have a function that generates a random 3-character alpha-numeric string. I need to modify it in such a way that the new string consisted of 2 alpha and 2 numeric characters. The combination of numbers and letters can be random.

```
function generate_random($length = 3) {
    $characters = '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPRSTUVWXYZ';

    $rand_str = '';
    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
        $rand_str .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters)-1)];
    }

    return $rand_str;
}
```

I need to modify it in such a way that the new string consisted of 2 alpha and 2 numeric characters. The combination of numbers and letters can be random. How do I do that?

Comment: You could split `$characters` into `$alpha` and `$numeric` having 2 loops or 2 functions or 1 function with 2 inputs

Comment: If `$length` = 3, then why would the output be 4 digits?

Comment: Create two arrays, one with valid alphabet characters, one with valid numerical characters. Pick two random elements from each array and create a string from them. Shuffle the characters of the string you just created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could separe numbers and letter. Then, append N values of each into an array, shuffle it, and the implode to get your string:

```
function generate_random($nNumbers = 2, $nAlpha = 2) {
    // prepare data to use
    $num = '123456789';
    $numlen = strlen($num) - 1;
    $alpha = 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPRSTUVWXYZ';
    $alphalen = strlen($alpha) - 1;

    $out = []; // New array

    // generate N numbers
    for ($i = 0; $i < $nNumbers ; $i++) {
        $out[] = $num[mt_rand(0, $numlen)];
    }
    // generate N letters
    for ($i = 0; $i < $nAlpha ; $i++) {
        $out[] = $alpha[mt_rand(0, $alphalen)];
    }
    shuffle($out); // Shuffle the array
    return implode($out); // Convert to string
}

echo generate_random() ;
// echo generate_random(2, 4) ; // example
```

Answer (score 2):

I would personally do it this way:

```
function generate_random($countAlpha = 2, $countNumeric = 2, $randomize = true) {

    $alpha = 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPRSTUVWXYZ';
    $numeric = '123456789';

    $rand_str = '';
    for ($p = 0; $p < $countAlpha; $p++) {
        $rand_str .= $alpha[mt_rand(0, strlen($alpha)-1)];
    }
    for ($p = 0; $p < $countNumeric; $p++) {
        $rand_str .= $numeric[mt_rand(0, strlen($numeric)-1)];
    }
    if($randomize) {
      $rand_str = str_split($rand_str);
      shuffle($rand_str);
      return implode($rand_str);
    }
    return $rand_str;
}
```

Inside I have 2 for loops, each one based on parameters `$countAlpha` and `$countNumeric`. I also have a 3rd parameter, `$randomize` that will allow you to randomize the output if you wish.